# ¿Cómo crear una función random sin usar módulos?

Tags: python, function, random

Me gustaría saber cómo crear una función que genere números aleatorios, sin usar módulos o librerías. Por ejemplo:

```
def random:
 codigo aquí
```

Comment: _Random numbers should not be generated with a method chosen at random_ (D.E. Knuth) En otras palabras, es un asunto muy complejo. [aqui](https://github.com/yinengy/Mersenne-Twister-in-Python/blob/master/MT19937.py) tienes una implementación en python puro del Mersenne Twister. El código no es muy largo, pero el algoritmo es inescrutable sin conocer la base teórica.

Comment: Podrías intentar conseguir la información del tiempo exacto de tu equipo, y utilizar el último numero. Por ejemplo si son las 11:29:45:921 el número aleatorio sería el 1. Creo que hay una manera de conseguir el tiempo a una escala atómica infinitesimal (nanosegundos o microsegundos), pero no estoy seguro, lei al respecto hace semanas. *Edit:* Lo encontré: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0564/